# Need to configure tracking code for Angulartics2

Tags: angular, angulartics2

I'm using Angulartics2.
I'm trying to set tracking code dynamically to have something like this:

```
ga('create', environment.trackingCode, 'auto');
```

But I couldn't find a way to do that.

I absolutely need to read this variable from `environment.ts`
Is there a way to read it in `index.html` from script tag.
Otherwise, Is it possible to remove this line and do it with Angulartics2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the answer here http://tech.webinterpret.com/how-to-make-google-analytics-work-in-a-single-page-application-spa/

1. Add `window.ga('create', environment.trackingCode, 'auto');` in `app.module.ts` constructor.
2. Set the property window otherwise it would throw an error:

   `declare global {
     interface Window { ga: any; }
   }`